# Verification Failed: URL is a not a valid routing destination

Tags: 2010, records-center, send-to-destination

I am trying to configure a send to connection in CA so that I can use the record center.  I have checked the URL and can browse to it no problem.  BUT when I try to save the connection I get this **Verification Failed: URL is a not a valid routing destination**

Comment: Is the content organizer feature enabled at the destination?

Comment: Yes it is enabled.

Comment: Extra note if I go to manage record center from the menu, I get Code blocks are not allowed in this file.